# How to permanently map samba drive on windows 10 version 2004

Tags: windows, hard-drive, samba, freebsd

The shared drive is based on freebsd and samba.

I need to map it permanently on Windows 10 pro version 2004.

My problem is: when I shut down my pc for long time then when I start it again the drive is disconnected and I must map it again.

I tried many ways to permanently mount drive and refresh it after startup, but unsuccessfully.

Thank you for help.

Comment: You can check desired mappings in a logon/startup/scheduled script; prospectively, renew them…